# SQL Count in a Join

Tags: mysql, sql-server, count, inner-join

Im simply trying to do a Count( Cars per Client )

So i try like this :

```
SELECT tbl_Clients.FirstName, tbl_Clients.LastName, tbl_Clients.Phone,
COUNT(*) AS   VehiculeTotal
FROM tbl_Contrat 
INNER JOIN tbl_Clients ON tbl_Contrat.Client = tbl_Clients.ID
GROUP BY tbl_Contrat.Client
```

and the easy way :

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Phone, COUNT(*) AS VehiculeTotal
FROM tbl_Clients, tbl_Contrat GROUP BY Client
```

but it look like i got the same problem :

```
Column 'tbl_Clients.FirstName'(LastName and phone too) is invalid in the 
select list because it is not contained in
either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

but dont want to group by them

and i need to show FirstName, LastName and Phone too !

help please

Comment: You can include them in the `GROUP BY`. If you're already grouping by the (presumably unique) client ID, it's harmless to include the less-unique `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `Phone` as well. Give it a try and you'll see.

Comment: Also, since you got a message requiring a `GROUP BY`, I'm assuming you're on SQL Server and *not* on MySQL. If that's true, please remove the MySQL tag from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use group by the result get partitioned into unique groups based of the column you group by. In your case the tbl_client.id should be unique, so it won't matter if any other columns used in the group by aren't unique. Say that you have two clients named John Doe with client id 1 and 2 the grouping would still separate them based on id, and no further grouping would happen.

This query should do what you want. I took the liberty to use aliases for the table names in order to make it a bit shorter and more readable too.

```
SELECT cli.FirstName, cli.LastName, cli.Phone, COUNT(*) AS  VehiculeTotal
FROM tbl_Contrat con
INNER JOIN tbl_Clients cli ON con.Client = cli.ID
GROUP BY cli.id, cli.FirstName, cli.LastName
```

Note that by using an inner join you're eliminating any clients that might not have any cars for some reason, and that might of course be ok, but if you want to return clients that don't have any cars you should use a left join instead like this:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, COUNT(tbl_Contrat.Client) AS VehiculeTotal
FROM tbl_Clients 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Contrat ON tbl_Contrat.Client = tbl_Clients.ID
GROUP BY id, firstname, lastname
```